# combobox with checkbox and a Filter in a web solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to do a combobox, but my user can select more than one option, so, it will be usefull if I do a combobox with Checkbox.

But this combobox with checkbox is bound from my database, so I need to put a filter inside the combobox with checkbox.

How can I do that via Jquery, or ASP.NET/C# ?

I tryied [this one](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/) but I need to put a filter.

Comment: It is not clear how your use of a database implies the need for a filter. Other than that, I think [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) has a neat solution to multiple selects. It gracefully degrades to a regular multi-select, too.

Comment: Well, let me explain better, for example, I have to do a select to fill my combobox, but and if the result is more than a thousand lines ?, I need to put a thousand options in my combobox, so I want to put a little input field just for my usertype the name of the option if he knows.

Comment: I saw a website (www.vrum.com.br) that has exactly what I want, but I don't know if exist a plgin like that.

Comment: @Lucas_Santos I give you an answer with the idea of how the site you write make it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `<asp:CheckBoxList` with on top of her a `TextBox`, and then you bind the checkboxlist using as filter what is typing on the TextBox.

Also if you place your CheckBoxList inside a div with limited width/height, and scroll enable, you have what you ask.

The menu opening, is simple open close of the div, with some delay.